# Environment Modules: can is-loaded look for a range of modulefile-names?

Tags: regex, environment-modules, modulefile

I'm getting started writing Environment Modules. I'm currently writing modulefiles that load the appropriate environment variables to run different versions of a program and want to display a warning if multiple modulefiles for the same program are loaded that might be conflicting.

So e.g. I have modulefiles named
program100, program102, program200, program304 etc.

So far in my code it looks like

```
#%Module1.0#####################################################################
##

if { [module-info mode load] && [is-loaded program100 program102 program200 program304] } {
        puts stderr "Other modulefile for program is already loaded, modules might conflict"
}
```

I would like to replace the is-loaded command by something like `is-loaded program*` that matches any modulefiles starting with 'program' if that is possible.

Thank you for any help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You may benefit from organizing your `program` modulefiles in a common `program` directory where all version-specific modulefiles lie in:

```
program/100
program/102
program/200
program/304
```

With this organization you can designate all these modulefiles by the `program` name so your test could look like:

```
#%Module1.0#######################################################################

if { [module-info mode load] && [is-loaded program] } {
    puts stderr "Other modulefile for program is already loaded, modules might conflict"
}
```